# Passing 'settable at queue time' build pipeline variables through REST api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Queuing build pipelines allows setting variables at queue time. If I queue a build through the azure devops REST API, how do I pass the values to the variables I would otherwise be manually setting from the visual interface? The [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/queue?view=vsts-rest-4.1) doesn't seem to have it but I could easily be mistaken. Is there a JSON dict that azure-devops will try to parse from the body of the request to accomplish this - if so what is its expected key?

Comment: Thank you Shayki x2. I will try and close this (I think?) if it works for me.

Comment: You're welcome:) If you don't success you can show the issue here or in your first question.